# How to manage QML ScrollView navigation with respect to child QML TextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a [TextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html) inside a [Scrollview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html) inside a [SplitView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html). I have a [Q_INVOKABLE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) function that I call when a row in a [TableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) gets selected to jump to a desired line in the TextEdit, this works fine. However, I need to adjust the ScrollView focus so that it moves when the selection of the TextEdit moves.
Identical behavior to selecting a compiling error on an IDE.

```
//main.qml

ScrollView {
    id: palGenTextScrollView
    anchors.fill: parent

    TextEdit {
        id: mainTextEdit
        text: fileio.palFileText
        wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
        selectByMouse: true
    }

TableView {
    id: errorsTableView
    onClicked: {
        mainTextEdit.select(palerrorviewmodel.goToLine(errorsTableView.currentRow),
                            palerrorviewmodel.goToLine(errorsTableView.currentRow))
        mainTextEdit.forceActiveFocus()
        //Call something to adjust ScrollView here
        //palGenTextScrollView. ??
}
```

I omitted some irrelevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `palGenTextScrollView.flickableItem.contentY` to set the position of your text. Here after is a small example working: you have a button for each line of the text, and clicking on it selects the line and centers the text on it. You can work on it for your own issue.

I couldn't manage to have your example working because the `palerrorviewmodel` element is missing.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ScrollView {
        id: palGenTextScrollView
        width: 200
        height: 100

        TextEdit {
            id: mainTextEdit
            text: "I have a TextEdit\ninside a Scrollview\ninside a SplitView.\nI have a Q_INVOKABLE\nfunction that I call\nwhen a row in a TableView\ngets selected to jump\nto a desired line\nin the TextEdit,\nthis works fine.\nHowever, I need to adjust\nthe ScrollView focus\nso that it moves\nwhen the selection\nof the TextEdit moves.\nIdentical behavior\nto selecting a compiling\nerror on an IDE."
            wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
            selectByMouse: true
        }
    }

    Row{
        spacing: 5
        anchors.top: palGenTextScrollView.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 20

        Repeater{
            model: mainTextEdit.lineCount

            delegate: Rectangle{
                width: 20
                height: 20
                color: "blue"
                Text{
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: index
                }

                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        var lines = mainTextEdit.text.split("\n");
                        var count=0;
                        for (var i=0; i<index;i++){
                            count+=(lines[i].length+1);
                        }
                        mainTextEdit.select(count, count+lines[index].length);
                        mainTextEdit.forceActiveFocus()

                        var maxY = mainTextEdit.contentHeight-palGenTextScrollView.height
                        var lineHeight = mainTextEdit.contentHeight/mainTextEdit.lineCount
                        var centeredY=index*lineHeight-palGenTextScrollView.height/2
                        if (centeredY < 0){
                            palGenTextScrollView.flickableItem.contentY=0
                        }else if (centeredY<=maxY){
                            palGenTextScrollView.flickableItem.contentY=centeredY
                        }else{
                            palGenTextScrollView.flickableItem.contentY=maxY
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```